# Django: Return all users based on number of occurrences in another table

Tags: python-3.x, django

Given the two models

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    trial_days = models.IntegerField(default=21)
    ...

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=65)
    Date = models.DateField()
```

How can I return all users that have at-least three blog posts?

I am currently iterating all the users and checking if they have three posts however I can't help to think there may be a more pythonic way to do this using Django..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to annotate each `User` with the number of related `BlogPosts. You can then use this annotation in a filter to get all instances where this value is greater or equal to three

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('blogpost')).filter(num_posts__gte=3)
```